# How to split a comma separated value to columns together other columns

Tags: sql-server, split, sql-server-2012

I have a table like this

```
AccountID      GEO

CT-2000       9.9582925,-84.19607
```

I want to separate the comma delimited string into two columns

```
AccountID      LAT         LONG 

CT-2000       9.9582925    -84.19607
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try with the next approach, using `LEFT()`, `RIGHT()`, `LEN()` and `CHARINDEX()` functions:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
   AccountID varchar(7),      
   GEO varchar(50)
)
INSERT INTO Data
   (AccountID, GEO)
VALUES
   ('CT-2000', '9.9582925,-84.19607')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
   AccountID,
   LEFT(GEO, CHARINDEX(',', GEO) - 1) AS Lat,
   RIGHT(GEO, LEN(GEO) - CHARINDEX(',', GEO)) AS Long
FROM Data
```

Result:

```
AccountID   Lat         Long
CT-2000     9.9582925   -84.19607
```

Comment: Thanks! works fine for me.